# Which non-EU/EFTA countries offer EC261 compensation?

Tags: air-travel, regulations, compensation, ec261

It is stated on the EU website that EC261 compensation is only offered if:

- the flight starts in the EU/EFTA, **or**
- the flight travels to the EU/EFTA **and** is operated by an EU/EFTA airline

However, in practice, several countries have started offering EC261 compensation independently from the EC261 rules.

Please list all countries offering this for reference.

Comment: Your statement above is incorrect.  eg, all flights on EU carriers are covered, not just those where the journey starts or ends in the EU.

Comment: @Doc Not what it says here https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm In any case, I don't know any EU airline with any route neither starting nor ending in the EU

Comment: You want "EC261" rules or just similar rules? Canada, if I remember correctly, implemented something like that.

Comment: There are many EU airlines which flight A->B->C, where A is in Europe, B and C large cities nor so far away, e.g. South America capitals, or Asia capitals. I do not know if they offer B to C (but 5th freedom of the Air is becoming more frequent). [interpreting "route" as "leg", not as "flight segment"]

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi "Ec261" with e.g. the €250. €400 and €600 compensations

Answer (score 3):

**To be continuously edited**

The non-EU/EFTA countries offering EC261 compensation are:

- Georgia ([SOURCE](http://www.gcaa.ge/eng/news.php?id=6148))
- Moldova ([SOURCE](http://www.airport.md/passengers-rights-en/))
- Serbia ([SOURCE](https://www.airserbia.com/en/footer_copy_menu/legal/passenger_rights/notice-on-passenger-rights-in-the-event-of-denied-boarding-and-of-cancellation-or-long-delay-of-flights))
- Turkey ([SOURCE](http://web.shgm.gov.tr/doc4/shy-passenger.pdf))
- Ukraine ([SOURCE](https://kbp.aero/en/pass/delay/))

Comment: I'm quite amazed about this. Looks like many of the answers here covering issues at Istanbul airport and/or flying Turkish Airlines may not be quite exact. It would be useful to compare the local legislation with EC261 in detail. I've gone very quickly through the Turkish one and it seems to match at first sight (only noticed a different compensation for domestic flights), but I really didn't go into the details, and as we all know, the devil is in the details in these matters...

Comment: @jcaron To me what matters the most is the 3+ hour delay compensation, for which I got €400 from Pegasus for a wrongful denied boarding Istanbu-Bergamo